# How do you get SQL Token authentication working within an Azure Python 3 Runbook?

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, azure, azure-automation

I have a Python 3 script in a Azure Runbook which I need to connect to a Azure SQL Server Database using Token Authentication.

The problem is {ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server} isn't pre-installed on the Azure machine, to which we have no control over. I did try to see if I could force {ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server} onto the box using os.system('msiexec') but this didn't work since the Windows Installer Service could not be accessed.

I don't believe there is anything wrong with my code as this works fine from my laptop. I believe this is purely down to the driver being missing in Azure.

Is there a workaround for this?

If anyone is interested, this is my code...

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python3
    
 import adal
 from msrestazure.azure_active_directory import AADTokenCredentials
 import pyodbc
 import struct
    
 resource = "x"
 tenant = "x"
 authorityHostUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com"
 clientId = "x"
 clientSecret = "x"
 authority_uri = authorityHostUrl + '/' + tenant
 resource_uri = 'https://database.windows.net/'
    
 context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authority_uri, api_version=None)
 mgmt_token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(resource_uri, clientId, clientSecret)
 token = mgmt_token["accessToken"]
    
 SQL_COPT_SS_ACCESS_TOKEN = 1256 
 driver = "{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}"
 server = "x.database.windows.net"
 database = "x"
 connString = "DRIVER=" + driver + ";SERVER=" + server + ";DATABASE=" + database +";Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Integrated Security=False;"
    
 tokenb = bytes(token, "UTF-8")
 exptoken = b''
 for i in tokenb:
     exptoken += bytes({i})
     exptoken += bytes(1)
 tokenstruct = struct.pack("=i", len(exptoken)) + exptoken
    
 conn = pyodbc.connect(connString, attrs_before = {SQL_COPT_SS_ACCESS_TOKEN:tokenstruct})
    
 cursor = conn.cursor()
 cursor.execute("SELECT TOP (5) * FROM Reference")
 row = cursor.fetchone()
    
 for i in row:
     print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

For your case, I would recommend you to configure Hybrid Worker Group , import all the require modules on HWR and execute your runbook on it. For more information about Hybrid Worker Groups, refer [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-hybrid-runbook-worker).

Comment: I understand this but if I have to operate my own infrastructure to run the script it kind of defeats the purpose of me using an Azure Runbook. To me the issue is more around the driver being out-of-date on the Azure hosted VM.